# Passing filename prefixes to a program as input

Tags: linux, shell

I have some files with the following names:

```
A-C-F3_accepted_hits.bam
A-VR-M6R_accepted_hits.bam
```

The files are stored on a Linux server. I would like to extract the string before the underscore (i.e. `A-C-F3`, `A-VR-M6R` etc.) from all the files with `.bam` extension.

Subsequently, I would like to use these strings as prefixes for output files generated by another program that will use the `*_accepted_hits.bam` files for input.

To be more specific, my input is as follows:

```
 samtools sort -n A-C-F3_accepted_hits.bam A-C-F3_sorted
 samtools sort -n A-VR-M6R_accepted_hits.bam A-VR-M6R_sorted
```

Here the samtools will sort the contents of A-C-F3_accepted_hits.bam. I want the output file with prefix A-C-F3_sorted followed by default extension. Likewise I have 17 files on which I want to perform this task. Hope this makes things clear.
Thanks.

Comment: curious Why 2 porgrams ?

Comment: @kkk  I need to use a specific program called samtools which is required in the pipeline of RNA-sequencing data analysis. For this program the raw data files would be the above mentioned .bam files. I want the output files to be named with the same prefix else the default will override the earlier output files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` to extract the prefix of filename and append it to the common part of filename.

```
OCOMM=_accepted_hits.bam
for i in `ls *.bam`;
    do
            OFILE=`echo $i | awk -F_ '{print $1}'`;
            FILENAME=$OFILE$OCOMM;
            echo $FILENAME;
    done
```

Comment: I have added some text in the last part of my question to be more clear. Can you kindly provide suggestion accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) script builds a string of command line arguments from files matching `.*_accepted_hits.bam` pattern, then executes `php /tmp/test.php` with these arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash -

args=""
while read name
do
    name=$(basename "$name")
    args="$args $(builtin printf ' --input=%q' "${name%%_*}")"
done < <(find -type f -regex '.*_accepted_hits.bam')
eval "php /tmp/test.php $args"
```

*/tmp/test.php*

```
<?php
$o = getopt('i:', ['input:']);
var_dump($o);
```

*Sample files*

```
A-C-F3_accepted_hits.bam
A-VR-M6R_accepted_hits.bam
X Y Z_accepted_hits.bam
```

*Sample output*

```
array(1) {
  ["input"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "A-C-F3"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "X Y Z"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "A-VR-M6R"
  }
}
```

Note, `eval` is generally considered unsafe, because of the possibility to evaluate malicious code (may be injected into filenames, in particular). Also note the use of built-in `printf` (*see `info bash printf`*) function which escapes the special shell characters.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. It is as follows:

```
for sample in A*_accepted_hits.bam
    do
        echo $sample
        prefix=$(echo ${sample} | awk -F_ '{print $1}')
        echo $prefix
        samtools sort -n ${prefix}_accepted_hits.bam ./tophat_sorted/${prefix}_sorted
    done
```